# How can i hide the first item when click the second item in ListView using Expandanimation?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I Using to develop listview acts like the expandablelistview its works fine but one problem wil be there when i click second item first item does not close

I am using animation class like

**ExpandAnimation.java**

```
public ExpandAnimation(View view, int duration) {

        setDuration(duration);
        mAnimatedView = view;
        mViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        // decide to show or hide the view
        mIsVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

        mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0- view.getHeight()) : 0);

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

            // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
            mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                    + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

            // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
        } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
            mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
            mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

            if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
                mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mWasEndedAlready = true;
        }
    }
```

**ExpandAnimationDemo.java** like

```
public class ExpandAnimationDemo extends Activity {

//  Boolean sameItemClicked=false;

    boolean boolitem = false;
    View PreviousToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.udiniList);

        // Creating the list adapter and populating the list
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item);
        for (int i=0; i<20;i++)
            listAdapter.add("udini"+i);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Creating an item click listener, to open/close our toolbar for each item
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {


                View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                // Creating the expand animation for the item
                ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                // Start the animation on the toolbar
                toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);

                  }




        });
    }

    /**
     * A simple implementation of list adapter.
     */
    class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getItem(position));

            // Resets the toolbar to be closed
            View toolbar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = -50;
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Myxml file is **list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
              android:padding="20dip"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!--***********************-->
    <!--*** TOOLBAR LAYOUT ****-->
    <!--***********************-->

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_marginBottom="-50dip"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:layout_height="50dip"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething1"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Harder"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething2"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Better"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething3"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="Faster"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething4"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="Stronger"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is developed based on this link
   https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample

this works fine but when select second item first item does not close please guide how to implement my requirement advance thanks

is there any solutions plz gudide me

Comment: Try with my below solution and let me know whether it is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.

```
mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                        int len = menuAdapter.getGroupCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            if (i != groupPosition
                                    && menuAdapter.getChildrenCount(i) > 0) {
                                mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
                            }
                        } }
                });
```